# NEW TOR VERSION problem

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, update

i am having a problem with the new gor upgrade.  i do too much work online to allow moving of the vertical scroll bar (off of the right border).

is there some way to turn that aspect off??  i will not upgrade with that item in place.  thanks

incidently,  not sure how to contact torproject with questions.  the result of a chat attempt looks like:

```
TOR CHAT NA
```

[15:54] qwebirc v0.92
[15:54] Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Chris Porter and the qwebirc project.
[15:54] http://www.qwebirc.org
[15:54] Licensed under the GNU General Public License, Version 2.
[15:54] == ERROR: Anonymous TOR usage is unavailable

pardon, i do not see a list of tags to choose from.  tag?:  new version, user setting PREFS, dead in the water / cannot use?  configuration?
maybe you can add a drop down box of tags?

Comment: hi,  can you please make the comment button larger.  looks like "supposed" to hit the answer button only / not even see the comment button.  problem:  hitting enter seems to push send on this.  just needed a new line.                                                                                  can hit bump on this?  i need an answer..  waiting.                                                                        how do i contact torproject support for help.   is there a:  support@torproject.org  email ??   thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable the grey border?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20691/how-can-i-disable-the-grey-border)

Answer (score 3):

This new feature is called, "Letterboxing"

> Tor Browser, in its default mode, is starting with a content window
>   rounded to a multiple of 200px x 100px to prevent fingerprinting the
>   screen dimensions. The strategy here is to put all users in a couple
>   of buckets to make it harder to single them out. That worked until
>   users started to resize their windows (e.g. by maximizing them or
>   going into fullscreen mode). Tor Browser 9 ships with a fingerprinting
>   defense for those scenarios as well, which is called Letterboxing, a
>   technique developed by Mozilla and presented earlier this year. It
>   works by adding white margins to a browser window so that the window
>   is as close as possible to the desired size while users are still in a
>   couple of screen size buckets that prevent singling them out with the
>   help of screen dimensions.

If you don't want to use it, that's fine. Just be aware that using Tor Browser in fullscreen mode can help fingerprint you as a user.

How do you disable it?

go to about:config

change the **privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing** to false.

How do you contact Tor Projects?

Links to the mailing lists and the IRC chat rooms are here: https://www.torproject.org/contact/

Comment: hi..  Thanks Much..  (comment here ok?),  to reply  i have been busy with sec probs/  not been able to upgrade tor or get work done.  been hacked.  had suggested to ms have window off view on right so can just move mouse to right edge wo looking at it: ie open oversize window),  eg explorer probs like: 1) click on dir left side and all drops from view, 2) move loc with arrow key & you are not really "in" new dir, 3) dir names hidden under right pane, 4) forced size dif cols right side, 5) etc, snap-to turned off/ new apps not switch on click),  just pointing out how easy it is to ruin purpose.