# Newbie Browser Window Size Question

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

I'm extremely new to Tor and Linux in general. I read that it's important to keep a Tor browser window open only at half-size and not open it to full-screen size to fit the monitor completely. Is this true? And if so, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable the grey border?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/20691/how-can-i-disable-the-grey-border)

Answer (score 0):

In the past keeping the Tor Browser at its default size was a good idea to limit browser fingerprinting, but this is no longer the case for current versions of the Tor Browser which use [letterboxing](https://support.torproject.org/tbb/maximized-torbrowser-window/). Now you are free to resize the browser window to any size you wish.